# malloc error - SIGABRT

Tags: c++, malloc, free

I'm learning ncurses, so I tried to make a simple snake game in c++. When I run it, after few moves I usually get error:

> malloc error - incorrect checksum for freed object.

What is confusing me is that I don't free any objects explicitly.

I would skip posting the code, because I'm not looking for that kind of help. My problem is I don't really know how to debug it. When I run it in lldb, it doesn't behave no where near as expected.

Could someone give me some directions for solving this problem.

**EDIT**

I figured where the error was, but still don't know how to fix it or what causes it.

Error:

```
void Snake::add_snake_part() {
  snake_part new_part = {.x = 0, .y = 0};
  body.push_back(new_part);  // Error was here
}
```

You can see `snake_part` is a struct by its initialization. The error seems to be with `body.push_back(new_part);`

Comment: Maybe you are not freeing anything, but ncurses may be - it looks like some of your code has corrupted some of the malloc/free data structures. For more help, you need to post some code.

Comment: incorrect checksum often means that either free is looking in the wrong place for its book-keeping structure because the pointer doesn't point where it should or the book-keeping structure has been smashed by an out-of-bounds access. Check the bounds on any loops you are using and make sure any array indexing math checks out. If possible use `at` methods over `operator[]` until you've squashed all the bugs because `at` contains bounds testing. Other than that without code all I can suggest is you make sure you always know where your towel is.

Comment: @NeilButterworth would it be ok to post github link, since I don't know what might be causing the error?

Comment: @NeilButterworth Added some code. Would you give it another look?